# Getting null pointer in static method Junit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit4

I have following service

```
public UserActivityLog save(UserActivityLog userActivityLog){
    LOGGER.debug("User activity save called.");
    userActivityLog.setCreatedByUser(User.getUser().getUserId());
    userActivityLog.setCreationTime(new Date());
    return activityLogRepository.save(userActivityLog); 
}
```

I had written following Junit for test this but getting null pointer for User

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ActivityHistoryServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private ActivityHistoryService activityHistoryService;

@Mock
private ActivityLogRepository activityLogRepository;

@Test
public void testSave() {
    UserActivityLog userActivityLog = new UserActivityLog();
    /* Called some setter methods to set value here*/
    UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
    Mockito.when(User.getUser()).thenReturn(profile);
    Assert.assertNotNull(activityLogRepository.save(userActivityLog));  
}

}
```

User class is like

```
public class User {
private User(){}

public static UserProfile getUser(){
    /*some logic*/

    return userProfile;
}
```

}

Please help for this. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't mock static methods with Mockito. You can additionally use PowerMock for that.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are useful when they are useful. Use them as a replace for singletons is not a very good practice. Instead of what you have your code could look like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final UserProvider userProvider;
    private final DateProvider dateProvider;

    /** Constructor that sets all attributes */
    public MyClass(...) {...}

    public UserActivityLog save(UserActivityLog userActivityLog){
        LOGGER.debug("User activity save called.");
        userActivityLog.setCreatedByUser(userProvider.get().getUserId());
        userActivityLog.setCreationTime(dateProvider.get());
        return activityLogRepository.save(userActivityLog); 
    }
}
```

`Provider` classes are quite simple. They just have a `get()` method that returns an instance of required type:

```
public class DateProvider {
    public Date get() {
        return new Date();
    }
}
public class UserProvider {
    public User get() {
        ...
    }
}
```

With this setup you can easily mock the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need PowerMock to mock the static methods.
Refer:
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/03/junit-testing-using-mockito-powermock/